# Exchange 2013 + alias delimiter

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Does Exchange 2013 support the use of the + delimiter (sometimes described as "alias").
This seems like a well documented part of the email spec (used by zendesk and others), but in testing Exchange fails horribly. Maybe there is a patch I am missing.

I.e. can exchange receive an email sent to myname+an_alias@domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Exchange does not support this use of the `+` character, and I'm not aware of any tools or scripts you could use to make it, either.